# How to Handle Null Pointer under Optional.ofNullable as its nested?

Tags: java, option-type

```java
    public void createEmployessList() {
        List<EmployeeVO> empListVO = Optional.ofNullable(
                empListResponse.getEmpListResult().getEmpLite().getEmpInfoLite()
        ).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                .stream()
                .map(temp -> {
                    EmployeeVO empVO = new EmployeeVO();
                    return empVO;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

How to handle Null Pointer Exception under the above code as any of them might be null
empListResponse.getEmpListResult().getEmpLite().getEmpInfoLite()

Comment: there is a code smell here ! message chains : `empListResponse.getEmpListResult().getEmpLite().getEmpInfoLite()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just chain multiple calls to `map` in which you unwrap your object.

```
List<EmployeeVO> empListVO = Optional.ofNullable(empListResponse)
    .map(e -> e.getEmpListResult())
    .map(e -> e.getEmpLite())
    .map(e -> getEmpInfoLite())
    .stream()
    .map(temp -> {
        EmployeeVO empVO = new EmployeeVO();
        return empVO;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: You've written `.orElseGet(Collections::emptyList).stream()` which may be shortened to simply `.stream()` when you're using Java 9 or above.

Second Note: A `Stream` doesn't really make sense here in my opinion, normal operations on the `Optional` would be enough, as the APIs are very similar

Comment: Thank You , but you are missing this condition returning empty result (.orElseGet(Collections::emptyList))

Comment: @Pavan read the paragraph after the code block, in Java 9 it is not needed when you directly convert it to a stream